# What exactly is LoaderOptionsPlugin

Tags: webpack

Could you tell me what exactly the use case of LoaderOptionsPlugin and should we use it in webpack 4

I read in the documentation that this is for migration from webpack 1 to 2. But dont understand how to use it and what is used for

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/loader-options-plugin/